# image loaded with background-image doesn't show up

Tags: html, css

I'm really confused, I'm trying to create a landing page with an icon and some buttons, but I can't manage to make the background image I'm using show up, even if it's loaded according to Chrome's development kit

I only have these lines:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="tryhard">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Chargement des scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.tryhard{
  background: url(../img/guitare.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover; 
  -moz-background-size: cover; 
  -o-background-size: cover; 
  background-size: cover; 
}
```

This should be enough to make my image appear, but it doesn't show up on any of my browsers, while I can see it working on other websites...
My image weights 924 ko, and its dimensions are 2304x1536 pixels...

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: What if you set width and height to the `.tryhard` div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have reputation enough to comment, I'll post it here.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wdcur80/2/)

```
.row {
  height: <define height here>;
}

height: 100%;
```

The height: 100% will make it the same height of it's parent element, which is 'row'.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The tryhard div lacks dimensions (width, height). Set some values for height and width or add some content (currently it is an empty div without padding, so it is 0 x 0) and you will see your background image

Comment: Thank you for this answer, is there a way to set the image at its maximum, like height:100% or something ?

Comment: What maximum do you mean? The height of the parent div (row) or the bounds of the image (2304x1536)?

Comment: Let's say the parent div, how could I do that?